# Permuation with repeated letters and consecutive letters not same

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, permutation, formula

I have been trying to solve a question on permutation and haven't really been successful. I want to generate all the permutations of a specified length that start with a letter and end with the same,and no two consecutive letters should be the same. The permutations generated can have repeated letters.
For example,
if the array has {a,b,c,d} and i want all the permutations that start and end with a.
The answer should be:
abca
abda
acba
acda
If the array is {a,b,c,d,e}
Output:
abcda
abada
abdca
abaca
acbda
acada
acdba
acaba
adbca
adaca
adcba
adaba
abcba
ababa
abdba
acbca
acaca
acdca
adbda
adcda
adada

I even would like to know if there is some way by which i can directly get to know the no.of solutions I will get for an array by some formula..
Thank You everyone in advance..

Comment: " get to know the no.of solutions" There's a linear recurrence that I'm sure math.SE would be happy to solve for you.

Comment: how can I get SE to answer this??:D

Comment: Post it on http://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I posted you mathematical explanation below - edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algoritm is as follows. You start from some letter a and then have a set of all letters which you can use next. Then for each element from the set you expand a to ab ac ad. Then you add a back to set and  remove b, c, d from set for each of the new words correspondingly. After that you do the same (recursion). The only tricky part is when you are aboit to finish. Then you also need to remove letter from which you started before you choose second to last letter.

As for mathematics formula:

Let denote `T(n,l)` as number of "permutations" of length `l` and alphabet of size `n`. 
Now we can devise the following recursion:

```
T(n,3) = n - 1 // a(something other than a)a
T(n,k) = (n-1)^(l-2) - T(n, k-1)
```

What happens in the recursive case. We start from considering the case when last and second to last letter may be equal. So we have `a(letter other than previous, so (n-1) choices)^(l-2)` and finally we substract these cases where first letter equals to second to last, which is `T(n, k-1)`.

To compute it efficiently on computer use dynamic programming or memoization.

Comment: I understand what you have said.. bt the process u mentioned will take a lot of time.. is there some formula from which i can get the no of combinations that satisfy the problem statement??

Answer (score 0):

First thing, maybe you should have split your question in two. One for the "math" part of stack exchange, the one with the number of possibilities and the other one about the generation of it with an algorithm.

Math answer:

If I understand correctly you want your string to begin and start with a certain letter, "a" for example. Then the number of permutation depends on the size of your generated array. For the problem described by you you need to understand your string as "a**a" where "*" can take a number of values. A star can be filled in 26 ways( number of letters in the alphabet) minus the number of letters that are incompatible with your rules. Therefore the first star has a maximum number of 25 possibilities (because you can't repeat "a" in two consecutive characters). the second star can only have 24 possibilities due to the fact that it can't be "a" or the letter before it (26-2=24). Then, when we compose the possibilities you have 25*24 combination.

With a string of size n characters (excluding the first and the last that are set from the beginning) you have 25^(n-1)*24 combinations.

For the algorithm part:

See [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) for an easy to implement, and quite fast way to generate what you need. You simply go through your string and set those unknown characters (the *s) to values that do not repeat the same letter and so on until you have generated all the values.

From the way your question is phrased I  think your question is some sort of a homework so it would be better if you write your own algorithm instead of using STL and so on.

Comment: You can have repeated letters, just not consecutively.

Comment: Will keep the splitting of the question in mind the next time.. :) Thanks for the reply.. And yes the question is not one from my homework.. was trying to solve a question in a coding competition..

Answer (score -1):

You can use next_permutation algorithm from STL

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation, std::sort

int main () {
char mychars[] = "abc";;

std::sort (mychars,mychars+3);

std::cout << "The 3! possible permutations with 3 elements:\n";
do {
  std::cout << mychars[0] << ' ' << mychars[1] << ' ' << mychars[2] << '\n';
} while ( std::next_permutation(mychars,mychars+3) );

std::cout << "After loop: " << mychars[0] << ' ' << mychars[1] << ' ' << mychars[2] << '\n';

return 0;
```

reference -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/**strong text**

Comment: This has nothing to do with stated problem.

Comment: the example is of int array, you can just pass char array and get the permutations for it. While getting the next permutation, the result can be filtered

Comment: No. Number of permutations is much smaller than number of solutions to stated problems. There are roughly n^l solutions, while only n! permutations.